# Induction principle in its set formulation and in its property formulation: which one to use in a well-redacted Induction Step of an induction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, natural-numbers

I have read [this answer about the well ordering principle and the induction principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4280403/1021982). It especially says that "any proper axiomatization of $\mathbb N$ in modern logic does not involve set-induction or set-well-ordering". Then, it provides the right axiom schemas:

> **Induction**:
> $Q(0) ∧ ∀k{∈}ℕ\ ( \ Q(k)⇒Q(k+1) \ ) ⇒ ∀k{∈}ℕ\ ( \ Q(k) \ )$, for every property $Q$ on $ℕ$.
>
> **Well-ordering**:
> $∃k{∈}ℕ\ ( \ Q(k) \ ) ⇒ ∃m{∈}ℕ\ ( \ Q(m) ∧ ∀k{∈}ℕ\ ( \ Q(k)⇒m≤k \ ) \ )$, for every property $Q$ on $ℕ$.

---

This resonates with a question I had in mind: I have noted that the induction principle (especially in the "induction step" step) is not equivalent when it is formulated with the set-induction principle and when it is formulated with the property way.

Indeed, let $P$ be a property on $\mathbb N$. And let $S=\{n\ge 1 \mid P(n) \text{ is true} \}$.

Then, my thought was that, supposing $n\in S$ and proving from there, that $n+1 \in S$ is not the same as **writing** $P(n)$ and, by a succesion of implication, arrive at $P(n+1)$.

Indeed, the former supposes that $P(n)$ is true and the latter does not. So the former requires an extra assumption that we don't need. Even worse: in the former case again, we could be supposing that $P(n)$ is true for some $n$, when in fact the property on the whole $\mathbb N$ might be false. Supposing true something that is false is non-sense according to me (but I might be wrong).

---

Accordingly I have two questions:

- the first: "is there any link between the stackexchange answer I quoted and the thing I explain after ?"
- More practical question: "when redacting, should we avoid writing the Induction Step in the set-induction form and instead write it using only the property formulation ?"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is “writing” $P(n)$ and how is it different from assuming $P(n)$ is true? Conversely, how are we not simply “writing” $n\in S$, and through a sequence of implications, deriving $n+1\in S$?

Comment: Well I guess it's the same. The truth table of the 'implication' shows that if we assume $P(n)$ is true, showing that $P(n)$ is true AND $P(n+1)$ are true at the same time, is the same as if we show $P(n)$ (true or not true) implies $P(n+1)$ (true or not true).